# How can I alter values in a dataframe contingent on other values in r?

Tags: r

I've created a new variable in a dataframe. I want to fill this variable with the sum of different variable in my dataframe, but only for observations that share a third value. Additionally, I'd like to cumulatively tally my new value as the shared third value incrementally increases. For example, this is what I have now:

| evyy | PSS | MTI |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1966 | 5 | 0 |
| 1966 | 10 | 0 |
| 1966 | 15 | 0 |
| 1967 | 4 | 0 |
| 1967 | 7 | 0 |
| 1968 | 2 | 0 |

My desired end product looks something like this:

| evyy | PSS | MTI |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1966 | 5 | 30 |
| 1966 | 10 | 30 |
| 1966 | 15 | 30 |
| 1967 | 4 | 41 |
| 1967 | 7 | 41 |
| 1968 | 2 | 43 |

Notice how MTI for observations where evyy == 1967 is the sum of PSS where evyy == 1966 + the sum of PSS where evyy == 1967. And so too for 1968; 1968 MTI is essentially sum(1968 PSS, 1967 PSS, 1966 PSS) and so on.

I've been stuck on this for a while. The only thing I can think to do is some huge cumbersome string of `ifelse()` statements. Beyond that, I've made a new dataframe including only observations with a specific evyy like so:

`1. new_df <-  filter(old_df, evyy == 1966)`

`2. new_df$MTI <- sum(new_df$PSS)`

But this doesn't really do what I want it to. I'd prefer to keep everything in my original dataframe. Is this possible? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each `evyy`, calculate the `sum` of `PSS` value, then perform cumulative sum over each value and join the dataframe to get original data back.

```
library(dplyr)

#No need to have an empty column beforehand.
old_df$MTI <- NULL

old_df %>%
  group_by(evyy) %>%
  summarise(MTI = sum(PSS)) %>%
  mutate(MTI = cumsum(MTI)) %>%
  left_join(old_df, by = 'evyy') -> new_df

new_df

#   evyy   MTI   PSS
#  <dbl> <int> <int>
#1  1966    30     5
#2  1966    30    10
#3  1966    30    15
#4  1967    41     4
#5  1967    41     7
#6  1968    43     2
```

In base R :

```
merge(transform(aggregate(PSS~evyy, old_df, sum), 
                 MTI = cumsum(PSS), PSS = NULL), old_df, by = 'evyy')
```

**data**

```
old_df <- structure(list(evyy = c(1966, 1966, 1966, 1967, 1967, 1968), 
    PSS = c(5L, 10L, 15L, 4L, 7L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
    class = "data.frame")
```